# Checking if there's a hashbang in URL and if there's a value after it

Tags: php, hashbang

I have a single page PHP app and use my urls as follows with a hashbang:

- http://www.example.com/
- http://www.example.com/#!/ (if coming to the homepage from another url below)
- http://www.example.com/#!/aboutus
- http://www.example.com/#!/contact

Now I'd like to display content only on my homepage and to do so I need to check if the URL contains a hashbang AND if it's empty, i.e.: If the user visited the homepage and if the user came back to the homepage after visiting another section (which applies the hashbang to it).

I've tried the following however it doesn't display the hashbang part, only if I set the url in the `$curr_url` variable.

```
$curr_url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   //only gets the url part before the /#!/
$url=parse_url($curr_url);
echo $url["fragment"];
```

Comment: You cannot do this from within PHP as the client does not send the fragment-identifier portion of the URI to the server.

Comment: Thanks @Dai just found that out now :)

Comment: Thanks @Dagon I'm going to use JS instead